# How to stop redirection from local host to https

Tags: django, http, nginx, digital-ocean

I have a website using Django. There is always a redirection from our website as https. The problem that on localhost it cause a problem. The error is :

```
**An error occurred during a connection to 127.0.0.1:8000. SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG**
```

How to solve this problem? Please, I need your help. This problem doesn't exist before. I couldn't find the solution till now.

The nginx configuration is:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name  www.website.com;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

client_max_body_size 6m;

if ($scheme = http) {
    return 301 https://website.com$request_uri;

     }
location /static {
    alias /home/website/staticfiles;
    autoindex on;
    expires max;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml
               application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
}


location /media {
    alias /home/website/media;
    autoindex on;
    expires max;
}


location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    proxy_redirect     off;

         proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


   }


}

server {
listen 443 ssl;
listen [::]:443 ssl;

server_name IP website.com;

 ssl_certificate /home/website/website.com.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /home/website/website.com.key;
 ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
 ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
 ssl_ciphers '';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

client_max_body_size 6m;


location /static {
    alias /home/website/staticfiles;
    autoindex on;
    expires max;
    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml
               application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
}


location /media {
    alias /home/website/media;
    autoindex on;
    expires max;
}

location / {
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8000/;
    proxy_redirect     off;

    proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;


}
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to redirect? Are you trying to set up SSL locally when you're running your site via localhost?

Comment: I am using python manage.py runserver localy on my computer ... but http://127.0.0.8000 is redirected as https and this error appears

Comment: See my answer, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running the website locally you need to disable redirects to HTTPS
To do that set `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` to False in your settings:

```
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = False
```